# Failure to create a SQL Azure login with SMO

Tags: sql, smo, azure-sql-database

The following piece of code works with regular SQL and SMO. I'm trying to get it to work with SQL Azure. According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621784.aspx#ssmo), a limited subset of functionality that I need (database and login creation) should be supported. All the business checking whether an object exists will also fail: `server.Logins[loginName] != null` or `server.Databases.Contains(dbName)`. I can create a database if I dont check whether it exists or not, but i cant create a login. Anyone else ran into the same problem?

```
string connectionString = 
"Server=tcp:XXXXXX.database.windows.net;Database=MyDatabase;User ID=XXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=true;"

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connection);
    Server server = new Server(serverConnection);

    Login login = new Login(server, "NewLogin");
    login.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
    login.Create("NewStrongPwd123***");
}
```

Create failed for Login 'NewLogin'.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login.Create(SecureString password)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login.Create(String password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proposed answers to this question were identified on the MSDN Forum including a working approach. Please take a look at:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/26e42082-e649-4cde-916d-c1da2275e377